# When should I type ./ to run program and when I should not?

Tags: linux

I am very beginner in Linux. I am confused, can someone tell me when we should start the command line with ./ to run a program and when we don't?
I see they do not use it in tutorials, but bash would not recognize the program w/o it.

Thanks a lot,

Sadegh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you type a command, linux will finds executables to execute it.
the question is where should it search for?
there is a variable in bash which is called $PATH. lets echo it to see it's content:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/game/usr/local/games
```

so the os looks at **these paths**

So, what happens if your executable file is not in the $PATH variable????? (for example your scripts)
in this situation you should tell it where your executable file is!
if it is in current directory run this:

```
./program_name
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I now understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

'.' refers to the *current directory*.  Similarly '..' refers to the parent director.

Consider the following examples:

```
./foo
```

Will attempt to execute a program called foo in the current directory.

```
../foo
```

Will attempt to execute a program in the parent directory.  This and ./foo are called "relative paths" as they are relative to your current position.

```
foo
```

Will search for the program in your current PATH, which is a sequence of directories the shell searches to find executables.  You can see your value of PATH by enter ing 'echo $PATH'.

Finally, you can give an 'absolute path', such as:

```
/home/bar/foo
```

Which will use the whole path starting at root ('/').

Answer (score 1):

`./app` is specifying the path to `app`. Same as `/usr/bin/app` is specifying a path.

Unless the directory containing the app is on your PATH then you need to specify a path.